# Can carboncopies receive their copy of the envelope once the envelop is created?

Tags: docusignapi

We use template to manage the flow. However, due to some reason, we don't want to put carboncopies in the flow. We use a separate parameter "carboncopies" when requesting to create an envelope. It seems in this way the carboncopies can only receive the copy when the envelop is completed. How can we make carboncopies receive a copy once envelop is created without putting them in the flow?

Answer (score 0):

If by envelope is created you mean envelope in a `draft` status, then envelope will not be sent to anyone when it is in `draft/created` status. DocuSign will send email to the recipient only when it is in `sent` status. Now once envelope is in `sent` status, and you want to send it to a Carbon Copy recipient before envelope is completed, then you can put Carbon Copy recipient before the signer in the routing order. For instance, in below sample, I have added CarbonCopies in routing Order - 1 whereas signer is in routingOrder2, so envelope will first go to routingOrder1, then to routingOrder2.

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<Base64bytes>",
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "TestDoc",
            "fileExtension": "docx"
        },
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "carbonCopies": [{
                    "email": "ccemail@email.com",
                    "name": "CC Name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "routingOrder": "1"
                }],
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "signeremail@email.com",
                    "name": "A Name",
                    "recipientId": "2",
                    "roleName": "Participant A",
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "tabs": {
                        "signHereTabs": [{
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "anchorString": "/s1/"
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            },
            "sequence": "1"
        }]
    }],
    "emailSubject": "Test flow with CC",
    "status": "sent"
}
```